# Error in running Minecraft Bedrock Server on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, minecraft

So I'm attempting to run a Minecraft Bedrock Dedicated Server on **Ubuntu 18.04** and I've ran into an error in running the server file.  Console says this before exiting.

```
./bedrock_server: line 1: version: command not found
./bedrock_server: line 2: oid: command not found
size: '366639608': No such file
```

I used `chmod +x bedrock_server` to allow me to execute it, and I run the file with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server`.  Note that the `bedrock_server` file is the actual server file, and I am running it correctly, as you can see at [this](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock/) page under the Ubuntu download.  I am pretty sure I have all the files needed, and at their latest version.  If you need any other information, please ask for it.

Comment: Apparently you are trying to execute a file that is not meant to be executed. Perhaps you could [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1316461/edit) to show us the first 10-or-so lines of that file.

Comment: @user535733 the file is meant to be executed.  The documentation says to run it with that command, as you can see on [this](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock/) page.

Comment: You are probably trying to run the `bedrock_server` file alone and away from the directory extracted from `.zip` download. This file needs the rest of the directories and files that came with it and in the same structure. Try just extracting the downloaded `.zip` file and `cd` to the new extracted directory then run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server` from there. The `bedrock_server` should be already executable and if not then run `chmod +x bedrock_server` but **do not copy it** .. `cd` to its parent directory in the terminal and run it from there.

Comment: @Raffa I am running the file in the right directory.  Why shouldn't I copy it, does it mess up the file?

Comment: What I meant is don't copy this file alone outside the directory that resulted from extracting the downloaded `.zip` file. This directory contains other files and directories in a certain structure needed for `bedrock_server` to run correctly. It is supposed to be run in that same directory. .. copy all the extracted directory if you have to but leave the file in it and run it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had a corrupted file, and that's why it wouldn't run correctly.

Comment: I suggest you clarify what you were doing, which led to problems (either in the OP or the answer), and keep this answer on how you solved it.
Then, accept your own answer, and let the bounty go.
This might be helpful for others running into a similar problem.

Comment: Apparently my server hasn't been working for months (auto-updates itself every night, my kids just told me tonight it hasn't been working). I guess at some point the execution permission vanished from the file and just doing `chmod +x bedrock_server` fixed that for me.